# how to join table mongoose with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new in mongoDB and nodejs, and I want to join this query `dbconn.users_model.find({ upline: parent.userid, position: position}, function(err, me)` with my collections in mongoDB, I have three data collection in MongoDB, first collections is "account", second is "balance" and the last one is "users". Here's i show my own project code. I hope you guys understand, cause i'm not good at explaining something.

```js
dbconn.users_model.find({ upline: parent.userid, position: position}, function(err, me) {
            if (!err && me.length > 0){
                var data_node = {
                    name:me[0].name,
                    userid:me[0].userid,
                    upline:me[0].upline,
                    username:me[0].username,
                    position:me[0].position,
                    _id:me[0]._id
                };
                if(parent.hasOwnProperty('family')){
                    data_node.family = parent.family+'-'+data_node.userid;
                }else{
                    data_node.family = parent.userid+'-'+data_node.userid;
                }
                data_tree['level_'+level]['parent_'+parent.userid+'_'+position] = data_node;
                get_item(level,data_node,function(resp_get_item){
                    return cb('');
                });
            }
            else{
                var data_node = {
                    name:'___add',
                    userid:parent.userid+''+position,
                    upline:parent.userid,
                    position:position
                };
                 if(parent.hasOwnProperty('family')){
                        data_node.family = parent.family+'-'+data_node.userid;
                    }else{
                        data_node.family = parent.userid+'-'+data_node.userid;
                    }

                data_tree['level_'+level]['parent_'+parent.userid+'_'+position] = data_node;
                if(position_mapping.hasOwnProperty(''+parent.userid)){
                }else{
                    position_mapping[''+parent.userid] = {};
                }
                position_mapping[''+parent.userid][''+position] = 1;

                if(!(uplinelist.indexOf(myupline) > -1)){
                    uplinelist.push(myupline);
                }else{
                    uplinelist[uplinelist.indexOf(myupline)] = myupline;
                }

                return cb('');
            }
        });
```

[Hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuoU2.jpg)

If it's already connected with my collection in MongoDB ("balance" and "account"), it'll show every fields in that hover display.

Comment: What do you mean by joining? Do you want to run the same find query on the three collections and combine the results? In your code, you just do the `find` on `users_model`

Comment: yes correct, that's what i want, I want to run the same find query on the three collections and combine the result. So do you think there is a solutions to solve the problem? for now i'm stuck. do i have to query 'find' the others collection like i did to 'users_model'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 'Literally' nothing called `JOIN` in MongoDB queries. You need to populate the data from a collection and then you can either do a subquery on another collection or write the custom method to fetch data from multiple collections and create the dataset which you need to return from your query.

Please do not apply RDBMS queries/concepts with NoSQL databases.

Comment: I see,thank you for your advice. may i ask if do you have any example for me to see or to read?